# Changing colors of siblings fail with jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello I'm just starting with jquery and don't know why this is not working... 
I want to change the color of the link after it has been clicked. When other links are clicked links should turn to be white again, the current clicked item should be yellow...but all links keep being yellow...?!

Here comes the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adkWe/

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.main a').click(function(){
                $(this).css({"color":"#ffd601"});
                $(this).siblings('a').css({"color":"#fff"});
                });


            });


        </script> 

<div id ="navigation">
            <ul class="main">
                <li><a href="#test1">Test1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test2">Test2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test3">Test3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#test34">Test4</a></li>

            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple change you can make to your current code:

`$(this).parent().siblings().find('a').css({"color":"#fff"});`

Effectivly the `<a>`s dont have simplings, so you use `.parent()` to move the the `<li>`s and select their siblings.

Ive [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eJt2u/)

Al

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it via siblings you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.main li').click(function(){
 /*finding link inside the li */ 
 $(this).find('a').css({"color":"#ffd601"});
 /*finding siblings of li and then link inside it */
 $(this).siblings().find('a').css({"color":"#fff"}); 
 });
});​
```

Comment: Yes, and that is why it is selecting $('.main li') and not the link.

Answer (score 1):

You are targetting anchor elements **which are insider LI elements so they have no siblings !**

You could sometyhing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.main a').click(function() {
        $(this).css({
            "color": "#ffd601"
        })
        // go up to the UL element, find all anchors and exclude the current
        .closest('ul').find('a').not(this).css({
            "color": "#fff"
        });
    });
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/zgzzE/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/adkWe/13/

EDIT:

It uses the same principle but i've extracted the styling to a css class.

Answer (score 0):

the anchor tags are inside of list item tags, so they have no siblings.

```
alert($(this).siblings('a').length); // this alerts 0 in your fiddle
```

Fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/adkWe/23/

```
$(this).parents('ul').find('a').not(this).css({"color":"#fff"});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't acess siblings, because your anchor elements are wrapped within an li element.

```
 div#navigation
     ul.main
       li
          a
       li
          a
       li
          a
       li
          a
```

You could select every a withing the navigation like

```
$('#nav a').each(function(i,val){
    $(this).css(...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the parent LI siblings

```
$('.main a').click(function(){
       $(this).css({"color":"#ffd601"});
       $(this).parent('li').siblings().find('a').css({"color":"#fff"});
});
```

Using tagname as arument in parent() is not necessary, is simply here for clarity